# Activity load again in first time app Launch

Tags: java, android

I want to open successfullyadd.activity but it open my main activity and after loading main activity it load successfullyadd.activity. I want to open successfullyadd.activity from luckywheel.activity but it cut the luckywheel.activity and open home.activity then it open successfullyadd.activity.Bellow are the eg for better understanding

"A" to "B" and then "B" to "C" but it cut "B" activity then it Take recreate "A" then it took to "C"

I use firebase database.I remove the updatechildren code from my file and it solve but I need to use firebase and update the some children

```
final DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
final GoogleSignInAccount account = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(getApplicationContext());

    if (currentUser != null) {
         final String uid = currentUser.getUid();
         reference.child(uid).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
              @Override
              public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

              UserInfo info = dataSnapshot.getValue(UserInfo.class);

              assert info != null;
              String coins = info.getCoins();
              assert account != null;
              String email = account.getEmail();
              String name = info.getName();
              //final Date currentTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
              int up = Integer.parseInt(coins);
              int addition = up + 10;
              String updatedCoins = String.valueOf(addition);

              HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
              map.put("coins", updatedCoins);
              map.put("email", email);
              map.put("name", name);
              map.put("uid", uid);

              reference.child(uid).updateChildren(map).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
              @Override
              public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                   if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        loadingDialog.show();
                        final int intervalTime = 3000;
                        Handler handler = new Handler();
                        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                           @Override
                           public void run() {
                                 loadingDialog.dismiss();
                                 Intent opensuccessful = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), videosucess.class);
                                 startActivity(opensuccessful);
                            }
                        }, intervalTime);

                    }else {
                        loadingDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(ChoiceSelection.this, "Failed: Check your internet!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

               }
         });

    }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError){

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

PLEASE check your menifest file and make it as launcher so main activity will not load untill you do that in lickwheel activity

```
<activity android:name=".luckywheel">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
 </activity>
```

Comment: But my launcher activity is Splash Activity

Comment: It only cause on first time launch activity

Comment: you don't mention that above :) 
do you mean that you want to open added successfuly activity from splash screen but splash screen not wait response and move you to wheel screen

Comment: No, I want to open successfully.activity from luckywheel.activity but it cut the luckywheel Activity  and open mainactivity and then open successfully.activity

Comment: when open app which one is opened 
and please print your code in wheel activity

Comment: Luckywheel and I remove the firebase code and It was working fine

Comment: When I open app Splash Activity open then if user has login them mainactivity if not login activity

Answer (score 0):

You can clear the `BackStack` before going to `successfullyadd.activity`

```
Intent opensuccessful = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), videosucess.class);
opensuccessful.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK); 
startActivity(opensuccessful);
```